# SML: How to count the number of elements between 5 and 15 of a list

Tags: sml

1. How to calculate the length of a list with a condition on members?

Generally, the following is used to compute the length of a list

```
(* Compute the length of a list *)
fun length(L) =
  if null L then 0
  else 1 + length (tl (L));
```

but how to specify the range of member by counting only between 5 and 10?

1. If I want to use function `foldr` for question 1, how to do so?

Comment: Think about it like this: The function as it is now counts +1 for every list element it encounters. What change could you make to make it count +1, if the element is between 5 and 10, and +0 for all other elements?

Comment: I fixed the title. SML stands for Standard Meta Language, not Standard Machine Learning. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the lambda function for List.foldr, you should add 1 to the total if the element matches the condition, but 0 if it doesn't. This way, you can keep track of the number of elements that matches your condition.

```
val xs = [1,3,5,8,6,9,10,14,13,16,15]

val len = List.foldr (fn (x, t) => (if x > 5 andalso x < 15 then 1 else 0) + t) 0 xs
```

This is what you get when you run it:

```
val xs = [1,3,5,8,6,9,10,14,13,16,15] : int list
val len = 6 : int
```